# Can the histogram of a sample of data drawn from a normal distribution be multimodal? If so, what causes this

Tags: descriptive-statistics

As the title says, the question i have is if a normal distribution can be unimodal shaped in a histogram?

[Edit after reading comments]
Can the histogram of a sample of data drawn from a normal distribution be multimodal?

Comment: I must be missing something. A normal distribution is theoretically unimodal and hence should provide a unimodal histogram most of the time.

Comment: With the usual definitions of "normal distribution," "unimodal," and "histogram" this is a trivial question and scarcely worth answering.  Please, then, explain what you mean by these terms.  I suspect the meaning you attach to "normal distribution" may be quite different from the one that is standard in statistics.

Comment: Agreeing with the comments above. Please clarify your question, preferably with an example of your data. The answer to the question as is, is trivial: normal distributions are always unimodal and symmetric.

Comment: Did you mean 'bimodal' or 'multimodal'?

Comment: Sorry that i diden't explain my question good enough but when reading for 10 hours due to an upcoming exam, my brains thinking process slows down :( ... (maybe is should go to bed)..  Your comments have helped me more than enough, i did not understand what i was reading in my book for some reason and i just needed some explanation, which all three of you have provided me with, thank you :)!

It's just because i am working with a data-set where i have made a histogram (The data is normally distributed), and the bin most centered is at least 2x higher than the once on both sides of it.

Comment: Therefore i thought there might have been something to it than i don't not know anything about

Comment: Please edit your question to something like: "Can the histogram of a sample of data drawn from a normal distribution be multimodal? If so, what causes this?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certainly. It is caused by sampling variation.

- the count in a histogram bin is a random variable -- for fixed bins and fixed sample size the set of counts will have a multinomial distribution. The standard error of the bin count (conditioning on the total count) will generally be a little less than the square root of the expected bin count. Simple random variation will mean that there can be a dip between two higher bins (or even several such).

  In six attempts at generating a histogram (in R) of a sample of 100 random values sampled from a standard normal distribution, I had about 4 where there was a
  "dip" in the bins -  valley between peaks; of those, this one was the most
  strongly bimodal-looking of the six:

  [image: bimodal-looking histogram of a sample from a normal distribution, n=100. The counts in the five central bins are 11,23,15,20,11; a clear dip in the middle]

We see that the three central bins (counts 23, 15, 20) are fairly consistent with a unimodal set of expected counts and a standard deviation for each on the order of 4 or 5 (given that they're only weakly dependent).

I subsequently generated another four such samples and got a second histogram
that looked similarly bimodal. It seems that there's a fairly good chance of
getting something that looks fairly strongly bimodal even at n=100.

- The output of a histogram function in a typical stats package doesn't have fixed bins -- they depend on the data. This makes the actual distribution of counts in the histogram more complicated. While I don't think I could give an analytical estimate of the proportion that would have more than one peak, a high-low-high pattern of counts does happen quite often with typical sample sizes.
- if you mean "can there be more variation than we would regard as due to noise" then again, yes -- whatever criterion we set to reject random variation as an explanation, there's some chance that the observed counts will meet the criterion; though it may be quite rare if we set the p-value very low.